# How to export Google Chrome history for Android?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm using an Android 10 non-root device.
Please tell me how to export all the history of google chrome application of this terminal with csv etc.

I logged in to Chrome with a Google account, synced the history, and tried exporting with Google Takeout, but the history of chrome on the Android device was not included

I ran the following command on adb, but Google Chrome pre-installed on my Android device was not backed up
`adb backup -all -apk -obb -system`